# Can GAP find isomorphisms to permutation groups which preserve / have additional properties?

Tags: permutations, finite-groups, algorithms, gap

Let $G$ and $H$ be two finite non-isomorphic groups in GAP.

The GAP command

```
IsomorphismPermGroup
```

can compute permutation groups isomorphic to $G$ and other permutation groups isomorphic to $H$.

Suppose that $G$ and $H$ have isomorphic defect groups $D_G \cong D_H$.

**Question:**

> Is there a way to compute isomorphic permutations groups $\hat{H}$ of $H$ and $\hat{G}$ of $G$ with GAP such that $D_\hat{G}=D_\hat{H}$ are really the same permutation group with the same elements, and not only isomorphic?

Thank you very much for the help.

Comment: At first glance, this looks rather tricky even in theory. Is there a result that guarantees that this is possible at least in principle?

Comment: Thank you very much for the comment. Hm...I am not aware of any result of that kind, unfortunately.

Comment: The only solution I can think of is to systematically generate all faithful permutation representations of $G$ and $H$ of same degree, and for each pair to check whether the images of the $D$'s can be matched to each other by renumbering points.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much.